# Use new pod with cocoapods 0.39

Tags: ios, dependencies, cocoapods

I'm using Cocoapods 0.39 and am trying to use [this](https://cocoapods.org/?q=appsflyerframework) package (AppsFlyerFramework 4.6.3). How ever [the old specs](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Old-Specs) that 0.39 sources from do not contain this version. Setting the Podfile.lock file to ask for this version ends up in a failed `pod install` command. I'd rather not upgrade cocoapods right now since a bunch of other stuff will break. Is there a world in which this can work?

Comment: Have you tried to download it directly from its GitHub repo and install it as an external project in your app?

Comment: Yep trying that out. Was wondering if there was a way to make the project work through the dep manager though.